# Use multiple inputs from html form as variables in url for ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

I would like to use multiple inputs from HTML form as variables in URL for ajax call.

HTML inputs:

```
<form id="inputs">
    City name:<input  type="text" name="city" placeholder="Beppu" id="city_input"></br>
    State name:<input type="text" name="state"  placeholder="Oita" id="state_input"></br>
    Country name:<input  type="text" name="country" placeholder="Japan" id="country_input"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" id="submission" onclick="Transfer();">
```

I want to use the input values for my ajax call as following:

```
 var city_name ="Oita";
 var state_name = "Beppu";
 var country_name = "Japan";

 function Transfer() {
  var city_name = document.getElementById("city_input").value;
  var state_name = document.getElementById("state_input").value;
  var country_name = document.getElementById("country_input").value;
   Start();
 }

function Start(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city="+city_name+"&state="+state_name +"&country="+ country_name +"&key=EGJR94mKHwvc9rLhE"
}).then(function(data){

  $('#humidity').append(data.data.current.weather.hu);
  $('#wind_speed').append(data.data.current.weather.ws);
  $('#temperature').append(data.data.current.weather.tp);
  $('#temperature_min').append(data.data.current.weather.tm);
  $('#aqi').append(data.data.current.pollution.aqius); 

 });
}
```

The output will  be appended to following:

```
  <p><span id=humidity> Humidity: </span><span>%</span>  </p>
  <p><span id=temperature> Temperature:  </span><span>°C </span> </p>
  <p><span id=wind_speed> Wind speed:   </span><span>m/s</span> </p>
  <p><span id=aqi style="bold"> Air Quality Index:   </p>
```

Wish you a good day! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass all the variables to the function `Start` as these variables are used inside that function. Also you should not have body of `start()` by specifying curly braces.

Try the following way:

```
function Transfer() {
  var city_name = document.getElementById("city_input").value;
  var state_name = document.getElementById("state_input").value;
  var country_name = document.getElementById("country_input").value;
  Start(city_name, state_name, country_name);
}

function Start(city_name, state_name, country_name){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city="+city_name+"&state="+state_name +"&country="+ country_name +"&key=EGJR94mKHwvc9rLhE"
  }).then(function(data){

  $('#humidity').append(data.data.current.weather.hu);
  $('#wind_speed').append(data.data.current.weather.ws);
  $('#temperature').append(data.data.current.weather.tp);
  $('#temperature_min').append(data.data.current.weather.tm);
  $('#aqi').append(data.data.current.pollution.aqius); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you, Mamun! Your codes and explanation had been really helpful! However, I still cannot get any results. Is there something wrong with my HTML code maybe? I try to add alert("test"); inside my function Transfer() to see if it is triggered by the form submission. But nothing appears after I click the button.

Comment: @XiaocuiWu, if the url and other information is right then it should work....how ever I am unable to get any data as it is saying invalid city_name